# TextView Not appearing after listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to display the TextView after the listview in my XML I am using a diffrent XML to fill in the elements of th elist view . I added another textview after(below the listview) the list view but I am cannot see it...When I tried to place the listview its own layout i got a nullpointer...any idea?

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</ListView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
     />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have declared **height** and **width** with **fill_parent**.

Just declare `android:width="fill_parent"` and `android:height="wrap_content"`.

Once you make this change, your TextView will be there.

Comment: **To down voters**, let me know the reason exactly for your down vote? FYI, he just mentioned that another textview is not being visible in the screen. So i have provided solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout with having listView above of Text view with fill parent height, and text view to align bottom of parent with wrap_content.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</ListView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative for the RelativeLayout solution (and suggested by Mohamed):

```
....
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a relative layout would be best as jitendra suggested.
Alternatively, I checked the layout myself and the second `TextView` field showed up when I assigned a weight to `ListView`